# How do I search a string for a keyword, then print whatever comes after that keyword in java?

Tags: java, string, search

I want to search a string for a specific word and then print the next 5 characters after that word. I have no idea how to go about this. I have tried searching for tutorials but could not find anything.

Comment: I'll bet you can do better than this. I'll bet that you can give it a try and come up with something close. Why not prove me right?

Comment: you just described the algorithm to do it, now just find the correct methods... some reference for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: I have tried to write a program that will accomplish this, but I can't think of anything. Can you give me something that will help put me on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the indexOf method on the String, and then do substring for the characters after.

```
int start = yourString.indexOf(searchString);
System.out.println(yourString.subString(start + 1, start + 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with regular expressions using `Matcher` and `Pattern`

```
import java.util.regex.*; //import

    public class stringAfterString { //class declaration
        public static void main(String [] args) { //main method
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=sentence).*"); //regular expression, matches anything after sentence

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Some lame sentence that is awesome!"); //match it to this sentence

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) { //if it is found
                System.out.println("I found the text: " + matcher.group().toString()); //print it
                found = true;
            }
            if (!found) { //if not
                System.out.println("I didn't find the text."); //say it wasn't found
            }
        }
    }
```

This code finds and prints anything after the word sentence. Comments in the code explain how it works.